# My cards in Power BI won't filter correctly when I filter by a legend in a table in my report, what's the solution?

Tags: powerbi, dax

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL2W0.png)

When I go to select a legend filter the cards won't update accordingly to the legend. I have the same tables being linked as well. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Do you modify interaction? Select your visual, Format ribbon -> Edit Interaction

Comment: It still doesn't work if I do that as well.